# use javascript calling code behind Method

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, function

I want to use JavaScript code to call the code behind method. I tried something but it isn't working.

JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    function checkMe() {  
        alert("hello");  
        PageMethods.Counting;  
    }

    function onComplete(result, response, content) {  
        alert(result);  
    }  
</script>
```

Below is my dynamically created `<a href="">` tag:

```
string.Format(@"<a href='{0}' onclick='checkMe();' runat='server'>{1}</a>", newlink.NavigateUrl, dt.Rows[contID]["FAQTITLE"].ToString()) ;
```

When I click the `<a href="">` tag how do I call the below method?

```
protected void Counting(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
    //my code is here   
}
```

Comment: You can't mix server language code and client side javascript like that. They run at different times in different places

Comment: Are you using WebForms ? Then go for PageMethods

Comment: @Sami yes im using WebForms.

Comment: try using ajax to call code behind function.